# addBatch support in Spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: spring, jdbc

I want to execute multiple, separate SQL statements like in the JDBC cookbook:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.addBatch(
    "update registration set balance=balance-5.00
    where theuser="+theuser);
stmt.addBatch(
"insert into auctionitems(
               description, startprice) 
    values("+description+","+startprice+")");
```

Must I use the Statement object directly? I'm looking for some spring JDBCTemplate service that provides the same functionality.

Extra points: Even better would be a service that takes a text with multiple SQL statements separated with `;` and executes them all.

Thanks, Ido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JdbcTemplate` has two `batchUpdate` methods that provide this functionality ([javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html)). Which one you use depends on how much control you need. If you need full control, you can use the `execute(StatementCallback)` or even `execute(ConnectionCallback)` methods.

Comment: oh man, I missed the batchUpdate(String[] sqls) and saw only the one for updating multiple rows with the same statement. thanks.